# Openssl C++ AES decryption adding unexpected symbols

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt in C++ a file that have been encrypted with the Linux command : **openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -K "E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855" -iv "5DF6E0E2761359D30A8275058E299FCC" -p -in file.json -out file.enc** 
The decryption works well, but unexpected symbols appear at the end of the file when I print it in the terminal, as in the following image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOt1S.png) 
Here is my C++ code, can someone help me ?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *en, *de;
  en = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  de = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

  unsigned char key_data[] = {0xE3, 0xB0, 0xC4, 0x42, 0x98, 0xFC, 0x1C, 0x14, 0x9A, 0xFB, 0xF4, 0xC8, 0x99, 0x6F, 0xB9, 0x24, 0x27, 0xAE, 0x41, 0xE4, 0x64, 0x9B, 0x93, 0x4C, 0xA4, 0x95, 0x99, 0x1B,0x78, 0x52, 0xB8, 0x55};
  int key_data_len = 32;

  std::ifstream in("file.enc");
  std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), 
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());


  unsigned char iv[] = {0x5D, 0xF6, 0xE0, 0xE2, 0x76, 0x13, 0x59, 0xD3, 0x0A, 0x82, 0x75, 0x05, 0x8E, 0x29, 0x9F, 0xCC};

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(en);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(en, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key_data, iv);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(de);
  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(de, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key_data, iv);


  char *plaintext;
  int len = strlen(contents.c_str())+1;

  plaintext = (char *)aes_decrypt(de, (unsigned char *)contents.c_str(), &len);
  printf("%s", plaintext);


  free(plaintext);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(en);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(de);
}
```

And the function to decrypt :

```
unsigned char *aes_decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *len)
{
  int p_len = *len, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)calloc(sizeof(char*), p_len);

  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, plaintext, &p_len, ciphertext, *len);
  EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(e, plaintext+p_len, &f_len);

  *len = p_len + f_len;
  return plaintext;
}
```

SOLVED : I had to remove the PKCS#7 padding added by the encoder [PKCS#7 Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7)

Comment: You `malloc` `plaintext` but you never zero out the bytes so I suspect the last character is a random character or `null-terminator`.. Either use `calloc` or do `memset` on `plaintext` right after the `malloc` call and see if it helps? Also, why don't you use `new` operator instead of `malloc` since this is C++ after all? Perhaps you also need to have different lengths for the data and the decrypted data? Maybe the malloc needs to be len+1 but the parameters to decrypt don't need to be..

Comment: @Brandon I modified the above code with a calloc, but nothing changes... The last byte is a '0x01'...

Comment: Data is padded using PKCS#7 padding, which needs to be stripped after decryption

Comment: @yachoor Can you explain me how to do this ?

Comment: Check last byte and remove/ignore that many bytes at the end. The padding is x bytes with value x, where x is between 1 and 8.

Comment: @cocool; I just tested your code.. it works fine for me.. It does NOT print any weird characters in my terminal or my console (using Xcode on a Mac). However, if I print the hex, I see the end of the file contains characters `0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0`. so for me, the last character was 0x3 so removed 3 bytes.. for you, the last character is 0x1, remove 1 byte.. So yachoor is correct.

Comment: I did: https://pastebin.com/K7eK2Xta and it now has no padding..

Comment: @cocool openssl by default should strip the padding. I think in this case your data is not null terminated. Try setting `plaintext[len] = 0` after `aes_decrypt`

Comment: @cocool also `strlen(contents.c_str())+1` will cause problems when encrypted data will contain bytes with 0 value. You should use `contents.size()` instead

Answer (score 0):

The input length is incorrect - `strlen(contents.c_str()) + 1` will either return length including additional null byte which should not be included as it is not part of encrypted data, or length of data to the first null byte in encrypted data if there is one. You should use `contents.size()` instead.
This causes `EVP_DecryptUpdate` to decrypt all data including last block with padding and expect more data and `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` to fail after that. With correct length the padding from last block will be stripped as expected.

There's also issue with output buffer length - it's `sizeof(char*) * p_len` instead of `sizeof(char) * (p_len + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_256_cbc()))`. `EVP_DecryptUpdate` requires output buffer to be large enough to hold input length + cipher block size.

You should also make sure to use only `len` data in `plaintext` buffer - `printf` will output data until null byte, which might not be included in decrypted data.